# Girl that unwillingly becomes a cyborg during a rainy night

Tags: story-identification, cyborg

I watched it once on TV.  Not sure if it was a movie, or a TV show/series.

- Some guy was trying to capture some bad guys (how much I can remember) and his girlfriend or maybe his female police partner (not sure - maybe both), got into a car accident, or was otherwise wounded by those bad guys.
  She wound up in "hospital", where they turned her into a cyborg!
  She woke up during the operation and escaped through the hallways to the hospital roof, where it is shown to be night-time and raining.
  The guy shows up on the rooftop as well, and the two start arguing in the rain, where she says something like "I'm a monster", or "I'm a freak" and shows her robotic hand! It's similar to a scene from *Terminator 2: Judgment Day* - with a robotic arm, half in skin, half machine, robotic fingers wiggling in the rain, with rain drops bouncing off of them.
- At the end of movie, when they beat those bad guys... they are in an apartment, where the guy sits on a couch, and she sits on his lap like a stripper and begins to "vibrate" - the camera zooms out and shows the building from the street, and there is earthquake like.
- The girl wasn't blonde... her hair was dark brown or possibly black.
- They were a younger couple.
- I think it's from the '90s.
- It's in color.
- Language is English.

I can say that it's not:

- The Demolitionist
- Robo Chic
- Steel and Lace
- Eve Of Destruction
- The Nemesis series

Answer (score 7):

It could be [Bionic Woman (2007 TV series)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0880557/).

- You aren't sure whether it was a movie or TV series.
- The girl isn't blonde, she has dark brown hair.
- She's nearly killed in a car accident, and is surgically reconstructed with bionic implants by her own boyfriend.
- There's a scene where she wakes up after the operation and sees that she has a cybernetic arm. She gets mad and starts lashing out.
- At the end of the episode, there's a fight on a rooftop, at night, in the rain.

Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNHGsxjDpkE)

You were mistaken in a previous question about *The Secret of the Incas' Empire*, where you said it was in English language, and described some scenes which totally don't exist in that movie.   So consider that perhaps you don't remember everything so well!

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches the description given in the question? [This guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/58193) gives some useful pointers for what to include.

Comment: She also unwillingly become cyborg because of car accident. And get mad when  discover what she become.

Comment: ArkhamWrath do a little research about Bionic Woman 2007. I writing on the phone and i don't know how to post a link.

Comment: Name of the link in square brackets, link in parentheses, no space in-between. But we do need you to edit in any matching details.

Comment: I don't know what and how to respond on Angelique answer.  Its 99% similar to what i search for and almost looks identical.  Bcs of this site rules i have o vote and check it as acceptable answer.  You win this round !

Comment: @AngeliuqeDeWill: Congrats on finding the answer. Sorry if we seemed a bit hard on you initially, but we get a lot of people who drop in, make a one-line answer as a guess, and then disappear again, which creates a lot of clutter (plus leaving other people concerned as to whether they should edit in the corroborating details or make their own answer).

Comment: Apology accepted.

Comment: I talked today with a cousin about this tv show! She says that just know that end of the ''movie''! The girl gets into the man's lap and began to vibrate and the whole building with the neighborhood shakes like a weak earthquake.  She is pretty sure (1000%) it's a movie, and she actually remembers a scene with a robotic arm in the rain same as me. I can't anymore accept this checked answer! Gonna undo it!